# html.erb does not use bootstrap style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My index.html.erb does not use Twitter's bootstrap style. The table appears very ugly without bootstrap, because bootstraps `zebra-striped` class is obviously not recognized.

But other files in my view are pretty bootstrapped, so the problem is within this small piece of code (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16306122/2013672))

Why is it so?

```
<table class="zebra-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
  </tr>

<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= student.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is not a real question. Maybe not a good one, but it is clear what was being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the docs will help for markup issues 
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

You should also markup your table a little more standard.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= student.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```