# How can I improve contrast on bootstrap zebra striped table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following twitter bootstrap table with zebra striping:

```
<table class="table table-striped">  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>Advantage</th>  
            <th>Details</th>   
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>aaaaa</td>  
            <td> bbbbb </td>   
          </tr>  
        <tr>
    <td>    ccccc</td><td> ddddd</td>
</tr>    

        </tbody>  
      </table>
```

The problem is I can't see the zebra striping! It all looks monotone to me. How can I improve the contrast of the zebra striping?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: it could just be your monitor, I know I have 2 diff monitors and background looks fine on 1, and almost white on the other. Always proof your design / look on other screens to be 100% sure of final result (if you care about that sort of thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building Bootstrap from it's `.less` files look at [variables.css](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less), specifically this line (from [github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L81)):

```
@tableBackgroundAccent:             #f9f9f9; // for striping
```

You an also use the [customizer](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html#variables).

As for a darker gray, this hex value could work: `#DBDBDB` (it's a slightly darker gray with the same balanced mix of red green and blue)

Comment: Thank you, I'll need to investigate further how to download and install the new version of bootstrap over mine using the optimizer.My version is 2.04 and doesn't have that variable

Answer (score 14):

The corresponding CSS is:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Add a new rule to your stylesheet that overrides this background color to something clearer for you.

Comment: Rick - any idea how to pick the color, I need some sort of color picker (#f9f9f9 doesn't mean anything to me)

Comment: Colors in hex go from 0 (dark) to f (light) in RRGGBB where R is red, G is green, and B is blue. When each pair is equal, the result is a different shade of gray. To darken the gray, choose lower values. Try `#eee` which is just a shorthand for `#eeeeee`. To visualize this, go to http://www.colorpicker.com/ and slide the color picker around the left edge (grayscale) and take note of the hex values on top.